# Measure Internet usage by computers on a network

Tags: windows, networking, internet, monitoring, adsl

I have 3 PCs running Windows(including my PC) on the same network. All three of them are connected to one ADSL Router. My requirement is to measure the internet usage(No. of Bytes Downloaded & Upload) by other two computers on the network. Also I don't have access to other two computers and therefore I can't install any Usage Monitoring Software on those two PCs.

Taking the above facts into consideration is there any way I could monitor Internet Usage on the network?

Thanks!

Comment: If your router was OpenWrt or Tomato firmware compatible that would be the easiest.  That would put linux on your ADSL device and each port should then have a statistics counter.  Otherwise placing another computer with an IN and OUT nic between the ADSL router and the other computers could be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a program called `NetWorx` to monitor Internet Usage. If your router Supports `SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol)` you should be able to use `NetWorx` to monitor your router.

Answer (score 1):

Remember though that using NetWorx to monitor the SNMP of the ADSL switch means that you are measuring all three PC's usage of the internet. You should be able to add SNMP agent to your local PC and monitor that as well which you an then manually take off the full ADSL total.

If the ADSL router doesn't provide SNMP then look through the ADSL web interface and see if your ISP has provided a running total and then you would look at screen scraping the value, or you can try and update the ADSL router firmware to a more generic version. It is possible that syslog may help you too depending upon the verbosity - but this is more used for alerts than for performance monitoring.

If you can persuade the other two PC users to install SNMP agents on their PC then you should be able to measure the network throughput on a PC by PC basis.